# How to perform an SQL query from a table based on values in other tables?

Tags: sql, sqlite

This is a pretty basic problem, but I'm new to SQL so it's giving me trouble.

Say I have three tables: X, Y, and Z.

X contains foreign keys for Y, and Y contains foreign keys for Z.  How can I select all rows in X which have foreign keys for Y, which in turn have foreign keys for Z, which in turn match some specified value?

For example lets say that these are the columns for each table:

X = "x_ids", "x_values", "y_foreign_keys"

Y = "y_ids", "y_values", "z_foreign_keys"

Z = "z_ids", "z_values"

I need to find out how to select all rows of X which I can trace down to z_values which equal the string "test".

Comment: Have you looked at `JOIN`?

Comment: Use `JOIN` ... by the way, if you showed us sample data it would be much easier to help you.

Comment: What kind of data would be best?  Actual table and row names?

Comment: @lurker would I place the JOIN statement directly after SELECT or FROM?

Comment: See the documentation, it's very clear on this. And there are lots of examples and tutorials online. `SELECT columns FROM table JOIN other_table ON ...`. You can have more than one `JOIN` in a `SELECT` statement.

Comment: It would be better to consult existing tutorials than to ask for a specific task/query implementation ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this:

**Tables**

X = "x_ids", "x_values", "y_foreign_keys"

Y = "y_ids", "y_values", "z_foreign_keys"

Z = "z_ids", "z_values"

**SQL**

```
SELECT * FROM Z 
INNER JOIN Y ON z_ids = z_foreign_keys
INNER JOIN X ON y_ids = y_foreign_keys WHERE X.x_values= 'HELLO WORLD';
```